# Why is '...' concatenating two numbers in my code?

Tags: php, numbers, echo

I have the following code snippet where I don't really understand its output:

```
echo 20...7;
```

Why does this code output `200.7`?

From what I know [**`...`**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) is the splat operator, which it is called in ruby, that lets you have a function with a variable number of arguments, but I don't understand what it does here in the context with `echo`.

Can anyone explain what exactly this code does?

Comment: [... Argument unpacking (since PHP 5.6)](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) [as per contained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/1415724) in the duplicate.

Comment: you two guys in the same class? http://stackoverflow.com/q/44023880/1415724

Comment: @JohnConde am starting to wonder if I did a bad close

Comment: @JohnConde seeing that you closed http://stackoverflow.com/q/44023880/1415724 I guess I just answered my own question *lol*

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant to my question @Fred-ii- or how do you apply that to `echo`? It's not a homework assignment or anything, just a piece of code I found acting weird and wanting to understand it

Comment: @Fred-ii- nothing to do with unpacking as you suggested otherwise. This is simply float to string conversions playing with string concatenation.  20 comes out as 20 and .7 comes out at `0.7`.  so you got `20`.`0.7`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not sure if the duplicate is a very good fit for this one, since the formatting of the code can probably confuse some people and that confusion isn't cleared in the duplicate. To explain to OP what is happening here: Basically you concatenate two numbers. If you write your code a bit different it looks like this: `echo 20. . .7`. Now you have to know that you don't have to write the 0 in PHP if you want to write `0.7` you can omit that. So basically you do this: `echo 20 . 0.7`. /1

Comment: And while concatenating those two numbers PHP will silently convert them to a string and basically append `"0.7"` to `"20"` which result in `"200.7"`. /2

Comment: @Rizier123 I reopened it.

Comment: @Rizier123 Side note: real funny though how another question earlier which is now deleted http://stackoverflow.com/q/44023880/1415724 was posted though. I doubt that was a coincidence.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I saw that one too :) Closing the second one as duplicate of the earlier question here would probably have been better, but OP deleted the question already.

Comment: @Rizier123 Shadow puppet syndrome; not much welcome, IMHO.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg The question is reopened and since you explained it first in the comments you can write a good answer if you want and explaining what is going on with this little code snippet.

Comment: And why does `echo 20..7` generate an error and `echo 20...7` not? Does php see them as `echo 20.[0] . [0].7;` ?

Comment: I don't get why `12..6` doesn't output, I expected that to be interpreted as `12` concat `.6`?

Comment: Maybe the confusion of the 2 post being the same was because I posted the same question on a facebook it group but no one was able to answer it

Comment: @csanonymus Yes PHP does exactly this: `echo 20.[0] . [0].7` YvesLeBorg explained it already in his comment and I also explained it in mine above.

Comment: @Martin PHP interprets `12..6` as `12. .6` which basically is `12 0.6` and since you don't have any operator in between those two numbers PHP does not know what you want to do.

Comment: @Rizier123 php has a splat operator too, not just Ruby http://php.net/manual/ro/migration56.new-features.php

Comment: @csanonymus I know, but PHP does not call it splat operator, that is why I explicitly wrote it in your question, so people don't get confused.

Comment: @Rizier123 I made an assumption that PHP was dealing with these figures as integers in the first instance but clearly that's not so, they're always going to be floats with `.0` parts, Cheers

Comment: @Rizier123 this raises another question : should this be viewed as a bug on PHP ie. should not the splat operator be parsed atomically, prior to any other manipulation?

Comment: Haha, @YvesLeBorg that's what I've been thinking too.. Is this a bug or a feature after all?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Not a bug. Since the `...` would need to be before the function argument and the argument itself needs to be a traversable, it can't be function unpacking.

Comment: PHP is not Ruby

Comment: @Rizier123 right .... throw TooManyLanguagesExceptions; yield asm;  ps, nice edit on the answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No this is not the splat/unpacking operator, even thought it might seem like it is. This is just the result of the PHP parsing process. Already writing your code a bit different might clear some confusion:

```
echo  20.           .           .7;
#       ↑           ↑           ↑
#    decimal  concatenation  decimal
#      dot         dot         dot
```

Now you have to know that `.7` is `0.7` and you can omit the 0 in PHP as described in the [syntax for float numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

```
DNUM          ([0-9]*[\.]{LNUM}) | ({LNUM}[\.][0-9]*)
```

So PHP just concatenates those two numbers together and while doing this PHP's type juggling will [silently convert both numbers to strings](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting).

So in the end your code is equivalent to:

```
echo "20" . "0.7";
//Output: "200.7"
```

Comment: To be more precise, PHP parses `20...7` the same as `20. . .7` and this is just another way to write `20.0 . 0.7`.

Comment: @axiac right, i had the correct version in my comment, will rix.